# How to call a controller directly using ajax

Tags: json, .net, ajax, controller

Let say I have 2 project ClientSide and ServerSide. I need to call a function in a controller of ServerSide from ClientSide. Can it be done directly using Ajax?
This is my Ajax code (it will work if the controller is put in the same project):

```
var url = 'api/values/insert';
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = "/index";
    }
 });
```

The local host for my ClientSide is https://localhost:44356, and the one for my ServerSide is https://localhost:44329. I have tried adding the local host into the url but it's still not working.

```
var url = 'https://localhost:44329/api/values/insert';
```

Is there any other method could help me solve this problem? I am appreciated for all the suggestion and answers.
For more specific information if needed, I am using .NET 2.1

UPDATE:
This is my controller code in ServerSide. If I put the controller in ClientSide, it works without any modification needed, so I believe the problem is about the connection between Ajax and the controller.

```
namespace RazorAPI.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    public ValuesController(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
    }
    // POST: api/values/insert
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public void Insert([FromBody]Data data)
    {
         //This call another function in ServerSide
        _dataService.Create(data); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of you ServerSide Controller Method?

Comment: What do you mean when you say «it's still not working». Do you receive any error message? Of course you can call any controller's action method with Ajax request because any Ajax request is just HTTP request.

Comment: I received status "(failed) net::ERR_FAILED" when running the post method. If I put the controller in the same project (ClientSide), it works fine and have no problem connecting to other code in the ServerSide, so I believe the problem is about the connection between Ajax request and the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working around with it, I found out the problem is because of CORS issue. This is how I fix it.

In Startup.cs file of ServerSide project, add the following code to Configure method:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
```

Add the following code to ConfigureService method:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders",
          builder =>
          {
              builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                     .AllowAnyMethod();
           });
});
```

Now use the url include local host to ServerSide:

```
var url = 'https://localhost:44329/api/values/insert';
```

This works for me but it will allow acess from any domain. If you need it to be only accessed by specific origin, change the code in Configure into:

```
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
```

And for the code in ConfigureService:

```
services.AddCors(options => 
{ 
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", 
          builder => 
          { 
              builder.WithOrigins("localhost") 
                     .AllowAnyOrigin() 
                     .AllowAnyHeader() 
                     .AllowAnyMethod(); 
          }); 
});
```

Thank you for all the help!